# I cannot insert two Greek words in my book text

Tags: characters, greek, books

I am having trouble including a couple of Greek words in an English book text. I have looked for answers here, but have not found anything that works for me and I've just got confused about it all.

If I use '\beta \phi' for example, I get 'missing $ error'. I've tried several packages, but can't get any to work, with font errors appearing or they turn all my text to Greek letters or errors from the packages. Many seem to be designed for mathematical equations and expressions.

In short, is there a simple way to include Greek words in my book?

Comment: Did you give the `textgreek` package a look?

Comment: I just included it as a package and used it. I don't think I'll have to write Greek words again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `\alpha` if you are not in math mode (`$\alpha$` will work). But I recommend using the package `textgreek` and its commands like `\textalpha`.

If you want to type greek characters directly then you should do it and switch your engine to Xe/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Great. That works a treat.